# How Django authentication flow works? [a particular case]

Tags: python, django, authentication

I am reading some code found on the Internet, and trying to make sense of it. I don't understand how authentication works here. Here is the code snippets.

the root URLConf

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),          
    path("", include("authentication.urls")), 
    path("", include("app.urls"))             
]
```

Then if we look at authentication.urls, we will see this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', login_view, name="login"),
    path('register/', register_user, name="register"),
    path("logout/", LogoutView.as_view(), name="logout")
]
```

Somehow it ends at 'login/' and login_view handles it. I don't understand why?
Ok, then if we open login_view:

```
def login_view(request):
    form = LoginForm(request.POST or None)

    msg = None

    if request.method == "POST":

        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
            password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect("/")
            else:    
                msg = 'Invalid credentials'    
        else:
            msg = 'Error validating the form'    

    return render(request, "accounts/login.html", {"form": form, "msg" : msg})
```

we can see that in case of successful authentication, it redirects to "/", which as I understand it, should create a loop. Because, when you go to http://localhost:8000 the first " ", include("authentication.urls")) will match it. And it all starts again.

1. When and why "", include("app.urls") will match?
2. When "", include("authentication.urls") matches, where does 'login/' come from?
3. Redirecting to "/" in login_view() doesn't create a loop, why?

Basically I don't understand how this whole solution works and will appreciate any explanations.

Answer (score 0):

> Because, when you go to `http://localhost:8000` the first " ", `include("authentication.urls"))`.

**No,** `include('authentication.urls')` will try to match the remaining item, here `/` with the url patterns of the `authentication.urls` module, so it will only trigger a view, in case the reaining string is `login/`, `register/` and `logout/`.

You thus can see the empty string the include statement:

```
#    ↓↓ prefix
path('',  include('authentication.urls'))
```

as a *prefix*. But the `urls.py` contains the `urlpatterns` and it has to match the remaining string (the string after stripping `''` from the beginning of the string in this case).

This thus means that `/` will *not* activate a view specified in the `authentication.urls`, since it requires `login/`, `logout/` or `register/`.

This thus means that Django will keep looking and likely will find a path in the `app.urls` that looks like:

```
# app/urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    # ⋮,
    path('/', some_view, name='some-name')
    # ⋮
]
```

and thus activate the `some_view` view.